# Android 4.0 and 2.2 giving different airthematic answer

Tags: android, math, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-2.2-froyo

I need to perform an operation like (We need to find op2 percent of op1):

```
2 % = 0.02
100 + 2 % = 102
(-2) % = -0.02
```

These operations are working fine on Android 2.2
The problem is that when I do the 3rd operation on Android JellyBean, The result is different
Jelly Bean answers as follows:

```
(-2) % = 0.02
```

Why so? There shouldn't be any code problem because it is working fine on 2.2.

### CODE

```
//op1 is 1st op in string format and op2 is 2nd in string format
double dop1 = Double.parseDouble(op1);
double dop2 = Double.parseDouble(op2);
resu = dop2 * dop1 / (double) 100;
```

Thanks

Comment: Paste the **actual** code where this happens please.

Comment: I will do it. But could it be code specific?

Comment: What do you mean by code specific ?

Comment: It is running on 2.2 and not on 4.0, then how culd it be code specific. These are just simple airthmatic operations.

Comment: Well i will need also the actual values of `op1` and `op2` too. So far for me it seems that you're executing a doubled negative percentage, so that's why you're getting + result, when you perform the second "(-2) %". One more thing, if `op1` and `op2` are integers, you can just assigne this percentage value to a double variable, there's no need to parse to double a rounded integer value. If both are integers, you just do `double resu = op1*op2/100;` if that's the formulae. Lastly - the thing you pasted under **CODE** is all the code which is executed on both 2.2 and 4.0 ?